AppSheet with ApiGee data source as a proxy for existing GraphQL endpoint
I already have a GraphQL endpoint. I want to use data from this endpoint (for various queries known only at the stage of creating different AppSheet apps) as a source for different AppSheet apps. Can I proxy my GraphQL endpoint using ApiGee and then, when creating an AppSheet app, use ApiGee as a data source and specify different GraphQL queries (as a parameter somewhere) at that moment to select only the data I currently need for this specific AppSheet app?
